# Box-Shadow and Overflow

Tags: css

With box-shadows, is it possible to use both "overflow-x: visible" AND "overflow-y: auto"?

It seems that if I include "overflow-y: auto" in my CSS, my box-shadow will be clipped in the x-axis as well... Ideally, the box-shadow would overflow in the x-axis...

Thanks!

EDIT: example code: http://jsfiddle.net/6nNbm/

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/UD8HF/1/

Comment: A box shadow will never be clipped in overflow, unless you're talking about a box shadow that belongs to a totally different element. Without seeing your code, we have no way of determining what you're talking about.

Comment: Not an answer, but relevant (and awesome): http://cssdeck.com/labs/creating-single-element-iphone-using-css3